# How do I tweak spamassassin scores on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: email, email-server, spam, ubuntu-14.04, spamassassin

I'm wondering what's the right way to tweak scores for Spamassassin's builtin rules.

I know how to edit `/var/lib/spamassassin/3.004000/updates_spamassassin_org/` but that doesn't feel right - my changes will either be overwritten by updates or will stop updates from happening - either way is not perfect.

Is there some syntax I can use to override scores of rules in `/var/lib/` with files in `/etc/`? Or is editing `/var/lib/spamassassin/3.004000/updates_spamassassin_org/` the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/etc/spamassassin/local.cf:

score USER_IN_BLACKLIST 15.00
score SPF_FAIL 0.5
score HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS 0.5
score RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW -0.5
```